# acceder a la base de datos de una aplicacion php en un servidor lin

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con Plesk Onix Versión 17.5.3 actualización #21. 
El servidor es Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS‬
Versión Php 5.6.30
extensión php: mysqli, curl, mbstring
phpMyAdmin versión 4.6.6

El caso es que utilizo la opción "exportar volcado" de la base de datos con la intención de poder acceder a los datos que contiene. El archivo que se genera incluye:

- error_docs
- httpdocs
- logs

Utilizo Notepad+++ 7.5.1 para abrir el archivo que se genera (nombreArchivo.sql)

En él encuentro la información de cómo crear las tablas con su definición

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plan_accion`;
>
> /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
>
> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
>
> CREATE TABLE `plan_accion` (
>
> `pa_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>
> (... resto de campos ...)
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`pa_id`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
>   COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Pero no puedo ver el contenido de la Base de Datos.

Si accedo a PhpMyAdmin de la base de datos puedo ver las tablas y si pulso editar puedo ver su contenido.

El problema es cómo ver en un documento el contenido de la base de datos. ¿alguna manera?

Comment: Que version de PhpMyAdmin usas?

Comment: La versión es: phpMyAdmin versión 4.6.6. Lo añado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que sólo estás exportando la estructura y no los datos, para ello en phpMyAdmin, cuando vayas a exportar dale a **Personalizado > Opciones específicas al formato: > Estructura y datos**. Así exportará también cada una de las filas como `inserts`.